# What Kind Of Token Does Parse (Back4app) Use?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have started to program Android Applications and I am using Parse (back4app) as a backend service. Does anyone know, which kind of token Parse uses at sessionToken (jwt Token?). I would be glad if someone could inform me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse Server generates session token using this function here:
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/de79b70cbce7abd3b8bae1ef66d5a15ab0a5f144/src/cryptoUtils.js#L42